# BeautifulSoup cannot concatenate str and NoneType objects

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

hi im running python 2.7.1 and beautifulsoup 3.2.0
if i try to load some xml feed using

```
ifile = open(os.path.join(self.path,str(self.FEED_ID)+'.xml'), 'r')
file_data = BeautifulStoneSoup(ifile, 
    convertEntities=BeautifulStoneSoup.XHTML_ENTITIES)
```

im getting the following error

```
  File "C:\dev\Python27\lib\site-packages\BeautifulSoup.py", line 1144, in __ini
t__
    self._feed(isHTML=isHTML)
  File "C:\dev\Python27\lib\site-packages\BeautifulSoup.py", line 1186, in _feed

    SGMLParser.feed(self, markup)
  File "C:\dev\Python27\lib\sgmllib.py", line 103, in feed
    self.rawdata = self.rawdata + data
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

i try to look everywhere but with no success ... please advise

Comment: "BeautifulSoup cannot concatenate str and NoneType objects", neither can Guido van Rossum, and he invented python!

Comment: @mikerobi: yes but they can take steps to prevent it from happening ...

Answer (score 0):

With the example ...

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
xml = "<doc><tag1>Contents 1<tag2>Contents 2<tag1>Contents 3"
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml)
print soup.prettify()
(...)
```

from [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html). I infer that you need to pass a string as first parameter instead of the file object `ifile`, try:

```
file_data = BeautifulStoneSoup(ifile.read(), 
    convertEntities=BeautifulStoneSoup.XHTML_ENTITIES)
```

Comment: i have try this but with no effect it works only when i use unicode(ifile.read(), 'utf-8', errors='ignore') instead of ifile ...

Comment: the it's fixed. isn't it ? what you needed is .read() + unicode. Am I right ?

Comment: no .read() didnt help, i have to use unicore errors = ignore ... whitch is wrong from my point of view and also i have to use the encoding in this case utf-8 but what if i get some other encoding? its wrong ... problem should be solve in the first place not just working around it

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too. This worked for me:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
file_data = BeautifulSoup(unidecode(ifile.read()))
```